# Python Join Objects

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I'm completly new to Blender. I currently work on a project which could utilize Blender for Beveling. To get in touch with blender I first played around with the programm itself and then tried to implement it into a Python script.

My goal/way to go is the Following:

1. Create Meshes/Objects from my custom Code.
2. Add different Materials to them
3. Select all
4. Join all Objects
5. Bevel by applying a Bevel Modifier
6. Seperate them by Material

Since I'm still in the "playground" phase with Blender i started with a simple one by one Cube as seen in the following Code:

```
import bpy

vertices = [
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),  # 0
    (1.0, 0.0, 0.0),  # 1
    (0.0, 1.0, 0.0),  # 2
    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  # 3
    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),  # 4
    (1.0, 1.0, 0.0),  # 5
    (1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  # 6
    (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  # 7
]

faces = [
    (0, 1, 6, 3),  # Frontface
    (2, 7, 4, 5),  # Backface
    (0, 3, 7, 2),  # Leftface
    (1, 5, 4, 6),  # Rightface
    (0, 2, 5, 1),  # Bottomface
    (3, 6, 4, 7),  # Topface
]

vertices_two = [
    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  # 0 (3)
    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),  # 1 (4)
    (1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  # 2 (6)
    (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  # 3 (7)
]

faces_two = [(0, 2, 1, 3)]


mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new("test_cube_half")
mesh_data.from_pydata(vertices, [], faces[:-1])

obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Half_Cube", mesh_data)
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Test_Material_one")
obj.data.materials.append(mat)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)


mesh_data_two = bpy.data.meshes.new("Test_top_face")
mesh_data_two.from_pydata(vertices_two, [], faces_two)

obj_two = bpy.data.objects.new("My_object_two", mesh_data_two)
mat_two = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Test_Material_two")
obj_two.data.materials.append(mat_two)

bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj_two)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

bpy.ops.object.join()
```

With this Code I create an Object which is the Cube **WITHOUT** the top face and an Object which is the missing Top face.

I execute this script via `blender --python my_script.py`.

The provided Code works until the last line, there it fails with the following
Error :

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

So now I have two Question :

1. Is the mentioned workflow of mine even possible with a script ?
2. What IS the correct context for `join()` and how do I set it ?

NOTE:

1. bpy is build for Python 3.6 (if anyone needs this info).
2. If i try the solution of [This Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13986/how-to-join-objects-with-python) i get the following error:

   AttributeError: bpy_prop_collection: attribute "active" not found
3. [This Questions Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43356/how-to-select-objects-and-join-them-with-python) does not work either and gives an AttributeError for `select` for each Object.

Thanks in adnvance.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add This may be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Need an active object**

The join operator joins all selected mesh (or same type join-able) objects to active object.  As proposed in link 2

[How to join objects with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13986/how-to-join-objects-with-python)

in 2.79 you set an object to active in scene with `scene.objects.active = obj`  whereas in 2.80 use the `context.view_layer.objects.active = obj` to make an object active.

Add this line before the operator and should work as expected.

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.join()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any source where i can read more about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from the above solution, here is a complete code for joining a collection of objects

````py
meshes = [mesh for mesh in assetCollection.all_objects if mesh.type == 'MESH']
for mesh in meshes:
    mesh.select_set(state=True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = mesh
bpy.ops.object.join()

obj = assetCollection.all_objects[0]
```
````